# 80s typography book with red apple on the cover

Tags: fonts, typography, book, history, reference-request

I am looking for a book from the eighties (or potentially older), a sort of font catalog. It was white, large format (approximately A4), and had a picture of a red apple on the cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the **Mecanorma** catalogue.

[image]

That particular edition was apparently [published in 1978](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL12649089W/Mecanorma_graphic_products).

Comment: OMG, it's that one! Thank you!